# How would you go about rotating a 3D array around a certain point (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, rotation

I can't find too much on it that I understand explicitly, but how would I go about rotating the data in a 3D array, for example, if the data inside the array represented a shape like a pyramid, how would you rotate it around the center point on an axis?

So say I had a 3D array of 3x3x3 and wanted to rotate that through the center? My best guess is taking each slice of the 3D array and rotating it around the center like a 2D array, so the array contents would look something like this:

```
Before:
[0][1][2]
[3][4][5]
[6][7][8]

After:
[3][0][1]
[6][4][2]
[7][8][5]
```

Comment: Have you tried something on your own? Please add your attempt on this question, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: You'll need to explain more about what your data represents. In `before` is (0,1,2) a set of (x,y,z) coordinates? By rotate do you mean to rotate a point in 3D space?